# Adding lists of data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data to add to my database, I'm not sure what my table schema should be. I have an id number for each specific user, 4 categories of games, and a possible number of items (0+) each user has for each game. I want to set a table for each game with the categories ->id and ->items, so I can save the list of user id's in the table, with the items they have for that game.

I can't seem to get it to work, I think because of the dynamic number of items for each user. Is it possible for me to achieve my above mentioned table schema? Why not/how?

I have been trying:

```
foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
        {    
         $sql = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO user_items_tf2 (items) VALUES (:item) WHERE steam_id = :steamid');
         $sql->bindParam(':item', $mydata->name);
         $sql->bindParam(':steamid', $steamprofile['steamid']);
         $sql->execute();
    }
```

Comment: You were mixing two `insert` and `udpate` query.

Comment: Why not have one table for users, one for games, one for items, a table that links users to games and a table that links userGames to items. That way it's all one to one relationships and is nice and simple

Comment: @scrowler I currently have a table for users, and 4 tables for the 4 games which hold all the possible items for each game. I don't fully understand what you mean. I'm not sure how to make each user have a dynamic list of items.

Comment: @Uchiha Because of the WHERE part? That still doesn't fix my actual problem though.

Comment: Please have a look over these links [insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) and [update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). Try to learn the differences between them

Comment: Scrowler is right. See normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numbers of ways to do this but one which is very flexible and seems to answer your questions would be this.

```
-- Players
CREATE TABLE player
    (`id` int primary key auto_increment, `name` varchar(255))
;

-- Games
CREATE TABLE game
    (`id` int primary key auto_increment, `name` varchar(255))
;

-- Items and what game they belong to
CREATE TABLE item
    (`id` int primary key auto_increment, `game_id` int, `name` varchar(255))
;

-- What games players are playing
CREATE TABLE player_game
    (`player_id` int, `game_id` int)
;

-- What items players have
CREATE TABLE player_item
    (`player_id` int, `item_id` int, index(`player_id`))
;
```

If you never needed to ask the question which users had a given item you could skip the player_item table and stuff the data (as JSON for instance) of their items into a column of the `player` table with a blob type.

Answer (score 0):

> $sql = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO user_items_tf2 (items, steam_id) VALUES (:item, :steamid)');